# Multiple, non-repeated angular directives tracked in parent scope

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

Here's an architecture question for ya'.

Say I have a controller "MyController" that encompasses a form. Within the markup for that controller, there are various form sections that are pre-defined (e.g. not defined via ng-repeat, this is a crucial piece of the requirements here) that all implement a directive "myDirective". Each section controlled by myDirective has two pieces of functionality:

1) It can be validated as a section (e.g. each element pertaining to myDirective is validated but no other elements on the form are).

2) The section is expandable/collapsable using another directive (which I've already written).

myDirective takes it's assigned node, and wraps it in a div which it uses to "expand" and "collapse" that section based off two possible triggers:

1) Clicking on an assigned "trigger" element such as a button saying "expand" or "collapse"

2) A property change on MyController that then triggers the element to expand or collapse.

The following are also requirements;

1) Only one section can be "open" at a time (they all default to closed)

2) Sections cannot "close" (e.g. no jumping from section to section) without first being "valid"

Given these requirements, my question is the following:

**How would one go about honoring "separation of concerns" here?** It seems to me that since these directives don't know anything about their neighboring directives (not even their $index since this is not ng-repeated) that they'd have to "register" with MyController in order to be able to coordinate their actions.

But then that introduces a whole set of controller-directive interactions that make them completely dependent on one another. I understand that it's an ideal to have them be completely ignorant of each other, but not only is there directive-to-controller communication, but there is also potential for controller-directive-controller-directive communication. For instance, if a directive notes that the user is ready to switch to it via some user action (e.g. finishing a form section or clicking the expand trigger of another section), then it must notify the target section to be closed, via the controller's registered section directives. But even then, its not so simple: the directive targeted for closing must be checked for validity, and if it's not valid the entire flow needs to be cancelled until the user fixes their work. If its okay, then we got back to the original directive, tell it it's okay to close, and then open the new target section.

Long story short, there's a lot of dependent functionality here. ideally there'd be some tracking array and a property stating which section is active on the controller, but I get squeamish when it comes to exposing what seems in this case to be more and more and more code between the controller and the directive.

So, in case you missed it before: 
**How would one go about honoring "separation of concerns" here?**

Thanks for reading!!

Comment: Instead of a controller wrapping myDirectives, you could have a master directive wrapping myDirectives. myDirective would require that master directive be present so they can communicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a case where a "required" parent directive is needed to keep track of child directives. In your accordion-like example, the parent directive will represent the accordion, and each child will represent each section of the accordion:

```
.directive("formAccordion", function(){
  return {
    controller: function(){
      var self = this;
      self.addSection = function(sectionCtrl, sectionElement){
        // ..
      }
      // ..
    }
  }
})

.directive("formSection", function(){
  return {
    require: ["formSection", "^formAccordion"],
    controller: function(){
      var self = this;
      self.close = function(){
        // ..
      }
      // ..
    },
    link: function(scope, element, attrs, ctrls){
       var section =  ctrls[0],
           parent = ctrls[1];
       parent.addSection(section, element);
    }
  }
})
```

`formAccordion` can keep track of each section and manage `open`/`close` requests. `formSection` can notify the parent when the form is completed (and "next" section needs to open) without making any assumption about the concept of "next" and whether or not it the section for it exists.

Comment: This is helpful. I've seen this example around but didn't really understand the difference between this and using the controller in the parent directives place (which seemed more "simple"). It also solves the problem of me not being able to "require" my controller (for whatever reason it couldn't find it, but I think its because "require" in this case can only require directives, right?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Out of curiosity why are you requiring the directive itself? That seems redundant/implied, but I've seen it around too and not been able to find an explanation for it that makes sense to me.

Comment: Never mind I think I get it; without requiring "formSection" you'd have no way to reference the controller, its for the "ctrls" argument.

Comment: @dudewad, right - requiring "self" gives you your own controller. `require` allows you to get controller instances defined by directives, rather than by the View (i.e. via `ng-controller`)